# correlation between inbount and outbound xml in soap handler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, handler

I am using org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin to create web services from my wsdl files. For these services, i wrote a simple **SOAPHandler< SOAPMessageContext >**  to log inbound and outbound xml.

Here i can check that xml is outbound or inbound:

```
(Boolean) messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
```

But there is a problem about correlation between them. How do i know that any inbound xml is corresponding to the any outbound xml? What is the best way to check that? For example, is there a way to do it in MessageContext modification?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SOAPMessageContext` is also a `Map<String,Object>` you could add a correlatio Id on the inbound side:

```
String correlationID;

if (!Boolean.TRUE.equals(messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY))){
  correlationID=System.currentTimeMillis(); // Better use somtehing more unique
  messageContext.put("INBOUND_ID",correlationID);
}else{
  correlationID= messageContext.get("INBOUND_ID",correlationID);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Is this message context specific for every soap request? I have only one service instance, and there is only one SOAPHandler. What if there will be a thousands of request concurrently? @Carlo Pellegrini

Comment: Yes a new  MessageContext is bound to each request.